# Reverse for 'logout' .. not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'admin/$logout/$']

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django 1.6.1 and I get this error at `/admin`
The project is a new project with no additional models being used.

```
Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'admin/$logout/$']
```

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Is there anything that I can add to the urls to solve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you have to remove the `$` from the regexp because you are including urlpatterns, hence appending the second piece of URL.

EDIT: to be more clear, the `$` in a regular expression represents the end of the string, and it would make sense in an urlpattern that points directly in a view.
but an urlpattern that `include`s another urlpattern is supposed to read only the first part of the URL, because the remaining part is read by the included one. from this the need to begin with `^` and to not append the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.